# Aggro Token and the First Activation Token

Tags: dark-souls

So, I recently came across the realisation that we were not using the Aggro token correctly.

To begin with, we were actually using the First Activation Token in it's place, assuming the other one was for a separate game mode (Like hardcore, or something). But upon reading the rules again, it mentioned the use of both. We were unclear about how they operated, but I think I have come to a conclusion - though I would like to clarify.

So, the way I believe these tokens work:

- The aggro token is passed around each turn. Enemies activate, player activates, pass on the token - enemies activate, player activates, repeat.
- The First Activation token never moves, until players open enter a new room. Players decide who should take the First Activation token, to begin the initiative order, and potentially, to see who should draw "aggro".

By that, I mean certain enemies have particular icons determining who they attack:

[image: Cathedral Knight] [image: Deacon]

In these two cases, the icon determines the target of the attack. The Cathedral Knight moves toward the player with the FA Token, and attacks them. The Deacon on the other hand, attacks the player with the Aggro Token, then moves away from the player with the FA Token.

Am I correct in this interpretation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the core set, enemies will either prioritise the player with the aggro token or the closest player.

The skull icon represents aggro. The circle represents closest player. See the Enemy Activations section in the rule book (pg 24) for more details.

The first activation token is just used to identify who will go first at the next encounter based on the fact that they were next in line when the previous encounter ended.

From the official rules:

**First Activation**

> No matter whether the encounter ends in victory or defeat, give the
> First Activation token to the player who is next in turn order after
> the last player who activated their character. The player with the
> First Activation token will activate their character first in the next
> encounter.

**Aggro Token** (emphasis added)

> When a character starts their activation:
> They gain 2 Stamina.
> **They gain the Aggro token**.
> They may swap items between their backup slot and hand slots (see ‘Equipment Cards’, p. 12).

**The Basics** p.19 (emphasis added)

> Once you’ve set up the enemies, terrain, and traps, place the
> character models on the entry nodes beside the door aligned
> with the tile the party moved from. Remember that a node
> cannot contain more than three models.
> **Next, choose which character led the way into the encounter**
> **and place the Aggro token on that character’s model.**
> Then the battle begins!

However, when you first enter any encounter you may determine which player 'lead the way' independent of the first activation and give the Aggro Token to that player.

Note that for the first encounter, the players decide as a group which player goes first. After that play goes around the table in a clockwise fashion.

> During the very first character activation, the players can activate
> the character of their choice. From then on, the order in which
> characters activate goes clockwise around the table.